# WPF DataGrid ContentControll bindng

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to make DataGrid with a structure as in image below.
[image]

To have two TextBoxes in each cell.

Ive made Class

```
public class ComplexTable : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ComplexTable()
        {
            FirstProperty = new FirstClass();
            SecondProperty = new Second();    
        }
        public class FirstClass
        {
            public FirstClass()
            {
                First = "FirstString";
                Second = "SecondString";
            }
            public string First { get; set; }
            public string Second { get; set; }
        }

        public class Second
        {
            public Second()
            {
                Third = "ThirdString";
                Fourth = "FourthString";
            }
            public string Third { get; set; }
            public string Fourth { get; set; }
        }

        public FirstClass FirstProperty { get; set; }
        public Second SecondProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ComplexTable> _testCollection = new ObservableCollection<ComplexTable>();
    private ObservableCollection<ComplexTable> TestCollection
    {
        get { return _testCollection; }
        set
        {
            _testCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TestCollection");
        }

    }
```

And a TestCollection that should be a ItemsSource for DataGrid.

My DataGrid

```
<DataGrid  CanUserAddRows="True"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First Column">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <ContentControl>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBox Text=" "/>
                                        <TextBox Text=" "/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Second Column">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <ContentControl>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBox Text=" "/>
                                        <TextBox Text=" "/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

I can't figure out how to bind those textboxes. Or i went in a wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

The datagrid sets the DataContext of the columns to the elements of the ItemSource. Every element in that ItemSource will be displayed as one Row. In your case the ItemSource is TestCollection. Therefore the DataContext inside your DataGridTemplateColumn is set to the elements of the TestCollection. If TestCollection contains ComplexTable elements. You can bind directly to the properties on ComplexTable.

```
var TestCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataForOneRow> {DataForFirstRow, DataForSecondRow, DataForThirdRow};

public class DataForOneRow {

    public string DataForFirstColumnFirstTextBox {get; set;} //left out raise of PropertyChanged for brevity
    public string DataForFirstColumnSecondTextBox {get; set;}

    public string DataForSecondColumnFirstTextBox {get; set;}
    public string DataForSecondColumnSecondTextBox {get; set;}
}

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First Column">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <ContentControl>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Bidning DataForFirstColumnFirstTextBox}"/>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Bidning DataForFirstColumnSecondTextBox}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

FYI: You have to raise a PropertyChanged event in all ViewModel properties.

Comment: but in my case in one cell i have not one text box, but two!! How to manage item source for such datagrid and how to bind it??

Comment: I edited my answer to show how this could be achieved. It could well be, that there is another way. But this will work, when you raise the PropertyChanged Events correctly.

Comment: Im sorry but this doesnt work. Try to run your code with two columns.

Comment: What exaclty does not work? If you still want my help, you should be more specific and constructive in your feedback.

Comment: The data binding doesn't work. DataGrid adds new line weirdly. Please test your code and you'll see.